# Debian 7.3 emacs packages cannot be authenticated?

Tags: linux, debian, emacs

I'm using Debian 7.3 (x64):

```
$ uname -a
Linux XXX 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.51-1 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I found this to be kind of weird, and I've never run into it before. Any ideas how to proceed?

```
$ sudo apt-get install emacs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  emacs23 emacs23-bin-common emacs23-common emacsen-common libm17n-0 libotf0
  m17n-contrib m17n-db
Suggested packages:
  emacs23-common-non-dfsg emacs23-el m17n-docs gawk
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  emacs emacs23 emacs23-bin-common emacs23-common emacsen-common libm17n-0
  libotf0 m17n-contrib m17n-db
0 upgraded, 9 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 25.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 81.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  emacsen-common emacs23-common emacs23-bin-common libotf0 m17n-db
  m17n-contrib libm17n-0 emacs23 emacs
Install these packages without verification [y/N]?
```

And `sources.list`. The Havana repo is for OpenStack gear:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb ftp://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main
deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main

# wheezy-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb ftp://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main
deb http://http.debian.net/debian/ wheezy-backports main contrib
# deb-src http://http.debian.net/debian/ wheezy-backports main contrib
deb http://archive.gplhost.com/debian havana-backports main
deb http://archive.gplhost.com/debian havana main
```

Answer (score 3):

These errors usually come up when you haven't added the appropriate [apt-key](https://askubuntu.com/questions/291035/how-to-add-a-gpg-key-to-the-apt-sources-keyring) on your system. I see that you have two repositories there that Debian may not be aware of, and it is possible that these packages are coming from these repositories. The ones I am referring to are below:

> deb http://archive.gplhost.com/debian havana-backports main
>
> deb http://archive.gplhost.com/debian havana main

This can also happen when you upgrade to a new version of Debian, or if the keys that you have on the current machine have expired. In either case, [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=7001019#7001019) might help fix the issue.

EDIT: use the above Ubuntu forums link with care, OP used it and it seems to have broken apt-get. Perhaps the Ask Ubuntu link is the better route to take.

Comment: Thanks Karthik Rangarajan. That last one from Ubuntu Forums was a bad idea. After removing the keychain, I get `sudo: apt-get: command not found` and networking is dying... I spent two days setting up OpenStack VMs on this machine, and I've got a feeling they are getting ready to become lost. Sigh....

Comment: wow removing the keychain removed apt-get? That's really odd. I'm sorry the link failed you :(, that was the best I could find among the lot - some of them suggested ignoring the message because it doesn't mean anything; somehow, I didn't think that was safe.

Comment: @noloader what exactly was the output?